# Como melhorar a performance desta consulta SQL?

Tags: sql, join

Olá, primeiramente vou passar alguns dados pertinentes para a consulta.

```
Tabela Contrato (id, id_cliente, status [ativo/inativo])
Tabela Cliente (id, nome)
Tabela Dependente (id, id_cliente, nome, status [ativo/inativo])
Tabela Cartao (id, id_cliente, id_dependente, status [ativo/inativo])
```

Sendo que tanto clientes como dependentes podem possuir cartão e também pode existir clientes que não tem dependentes associados, preciso fazer um select que retorne o id dos contratos que terão novas impressões (inserts) de cartões, estes inserts serão todos os os dependentes/clientes que não possuem um cartao com status 'A', portanto atualmente tenho:

```
SELECT CC.ID FROM CONTRATO CC
INNER JOIN CLIENTE C ON C.ID = CC.ID_CLIENTE
LEFT JOIN DEPENDENTE D ON D.ID_CLIENTE = C.ID
LEFT JOIN CARTAO C_CLIENTE ON C_CLIENTE.ID_CLIENTE = C.ID
LEFT JOIN CARTAO C_DEPENDENTE ON C_DEPENDENTE.ID_DEPENDENTE = D.ID
WHERE C.STATUS = 'A' --impressão apenas para ativos
  AND (
      --inicio tratamento de cliente
      (C_CLIENTE.ID_DEPENDNETE IS NULL AND 
         (C_CLIENTE.ID_CLIENTE IS NULL OR C.ID NOT IN(
             SELECT ID_CLIENTE FROM CARTAO 
             WHERE ID_CLIENTE = C.ID 
               AND STATUS = 'A' 
               AND ID_DEPENDENTE IS NULL
      )))
      --fim tratamento de cliente
      OR
      --inicio tratamento de dependente
      (D.ATIVO = 'A' AND (
          C_DEPENDENTE.ID_DEPENDENTE IS NULL OR D.ID NOT IN (
             SELECT ID_DEPEDENTE FROM CARTAO 
             WHERE ID_DEPENDENTE = D.ID 
               AND STATUS = 'A'
      )))
      --fim tratamento de dependente
   )
GROUP BY CC.ID;
```

As partes do NOT IN, é uma verificação porque o dependente/cliente pode ter um ou mais cartões inativos, e acredito que seja ai que esteja ocorrendo a perda de performance na consulta.

Comment: Talvez ajude se postar a estrutura da tabela completa, além de mudar a estrutura da query alguns dados podem ser indexados também.

Comment: Cole o EXPLAIN dessa query na pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@chavesfop, tente mover a subquery que está no seu where para os joins.

```
SELECT CC.ID FROM CONTRATO CC
INNER JOIN CLIENTE C ON C.ID = CC.ID_CLIENTE
LEFT JOIN DEPENDENTE D ON D.ID_CLIENTE = C.ID
LEFT JOIN CARTAO C_CLIENTE ON C_CLIENTE.ID_CLIENTE = C.ID
LEFT JOIN CARTAO C_DEPENDENTE ON C_DEPENDENTE.ID_DEPENDENTE = D.ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID_CLIENTE
    FROM CARTAO 
    WHERE STATUS = 'A' AND ID_DEPENDENTE IS NULL
) as C_CLIENTE_AUX ON C.ID = C_CLIENTE_AUX.ID_CLIENTE
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID_DEPEDENTE 
    FROM CARTAO 
    WHERE STATUS = 'A'
) as C_DEPENDENTE_AUX ON D.ID = C_DEPENDENTE_AUX.ID_CLIENTE
WHERE C.STATUS = 'A' AND
    (
        (C_CLIENTE.ID_DEPENDNETE IS NULL AND 
            (C_CLIENTE.ID_CLIENTE IS NULL OR C_CLIENTE_AUX.ID_CLIENTE IS NULL)
        )
        OR
        (D.ATIVO = 'A' AND 
            (C_DEPENDENTE.ID_DEPENDENTE IS NULL OR C_DEPENDENTE_AUX.ID_DEPEDENTE IS NULL)
        )
    )
GROUP BY CC.ID;
```

Comment: Pelo menos se falando de Sql Server (apesar de acreditar que o caso acima seja MSSQL, por causa da nomeclatura), ainda não vi uma consulta que uma subquery no SELECT/WHERE não degrade o desempenho da query ou que não possa ser subtituido por uma CTE (ou SubQuery nos JOIN).